# How can I "lock" an HTML canvas's aspect ratio to an image's aspect ratio and allow the canvas to resize in its parent div using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, html5-canvas

I am building a desktop app with ReactJS, Electron, and Material UI.  I have a densely populated UI, as I am managing inventory from a database.  Since I want my app to be resizable, almost every UI element is in a CSS flex box.  I have a parent "Paper" element from Material UI (think of it as a div with a background color) that is resizing correctly.  I want to load an image from the web into that "Paper", maintaining the image's original aspect ratio while allowing it to grow and shrink with its parent "Paper" div.  From what I've read on Stack Overflow and Google so far, I understand I can use an HTML canvas element to load the image from the web.  This is working properly.  I've also found some CSS from a blog that will scale the image at its original aspect ratio properly, but only in one dimension (width *or* height, but not both).  This mostly works, except the canvas horizontally overlaps its parent "Paper" div when the window is horizontally narrowed.  How can I make an autoscaling canvas that resizes in both dimensions while not exceeding the bounds of its parent div with ReactJS?  Is there a different component besides a canvas that would accomplish this in an easier way?  I can't set hard values for width and height of the parent div since its in a flex box.  Additionally, I would like the image to be horizontally and vertically centered in its parent div, which is not currently working.  This is what I have so far:

In my CSS file for the class:

```
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.styled-paper {
  textAlign: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(49, 51, 55, 1)',
  position: 'relative',
  width: '100%',
  /* this is to vertically align this div with two smaller divs next to it */
  height: '87%',
  border: 1,
  borderColor: 'rgba(108, 109, 112, 1)',
  borderRadius: 8,
  borderStyle: 'solid',
  borderWidth: '1px',
}
```

In the TSX file for the class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { isNull, isUndefined } from 'underscore/modules/index';

function isBlank(str: string | undefined) {
  return (isUndefined(str) || isNull(str) || str.trim().length === 0);
}

async function LoadImageFromUrl(url: string): Promise<string> {

  //URL shortening for database
  let shortenedURL: string;
  if (url.startsWith("https://tinyurl.com/")) {
    shortenedURL = url;
  } else {
  //Other async function that shortens URL with TinyURL
    shortenedURL = await ShortenURL(url);
  }

  //Get reference to canvas and its context
  let canvas = document.getElementById("itemImageCanvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //
  let itemImg = new Image();
  itemImg.onload = function() {
    var wrh = itemImg.width / itemImg.height;
    var newWidth = canvas.width;
    var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
    if (newHeight > canvas.height) {
      newHeight = canvas.height;
      newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
    }
    context!.drawImage(itemImg, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
  }
  itemImg.src = shortenedURL;
  return shortenedURL;
}

export default class ItemInfoEditPane extends Component<any, any> {

  state = {
    imageURL: '',
  }

  onChange = (event: any) => this.setState({ [event.target.name] : event.target.value });
  
  onImageURLChange = (newUrl: string) => this.setState({imageURL: newUrl});

  updateImageURL = (callback: Function) => {
    LoadImageFromUrl(this.state.imageURL).then(function(result) { callback(result) });
  }

  render() {

    const {
      imageURL,
    } = this.state;

    return(

      //Lots of parent elements and divs/flex box divs I removed for clarity that this block is nested in

                <div className="hRow textField triple">
                  <Paper className="styled-paper" elevation={0}>
                    <canvas id="itemImageCanvas"/>
                  </Paper>
                </div>

           //Other elements between these two, but this text field is where I grab the image URL from

                <div className='hRow textField'>
                  <TextField name="imageURL" label="Image URL" value={imageURL} onChange={this.onChange}
                                   onBlur={() => { if (!isBlank(imageURL)) { this.updateImageURL(this.onImageURLChange) }}}/>
                </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pieces of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62545730/8062444), I was able to solve my issue.  The CSS now looks like this:

```
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.styled-paper: {
  textAlign: 'center',
  width: '100%',
  height: '87%',
  position: 'relative',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}
```

Setting `max-height` and `max-width` allows the canvas to grow up to the parent's full size but not exceed it.  Setting the centering properties in the `styled-paper` section and the `top`, `left`, and `transform: translate` properties in the `canvas` section allow the canvas to be horizontally and vertically centered while growing and shrinking.  It also keeps the image's original aspect ratio.  The JavaScript now looks like this:

```
export default class ItemInfoEditPane extends Component<any, any> {

  state = {
    imageURL: '',
    canvasWidth: 0,
    canvasHeight: 0,
  }

  onChange = (event: any) => this.setState({ [event.target.name] : event.target.value });

  updateImageURL = () => {
    let image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => {
      this.setState((state: any) => ({
        ...state,
        canvasWidth: image.width,
        canvasHeight: image.height
      }));
      (document.getElementById('itemImageCanvas') as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    };
    image.src = this.state.imageURL;
  }

  render() {

    const {
      imageURL,
      canvasWidth,
      canvasHeight,
    } = this.state;


    return(
      <div className="styled-paper">
        <canvas id="itemImageCanvas" width={canvasWidth} height={canvasHeight}/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <TextField name="imageURL" label="Image URL" value={imageURL} onChange={this.onChange} 
          onBlur={() => { if (!isBlank(imageURL)) { this.updateImageURL() }}}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Setting the canvas's width and height with JavaScript allows the canvas to be the aspect ratio of the image.  This, combined with the max width and height properties in the CSS, is what allows the image to scale up to the size of the parent div, but not larger than it.  In my case, a user can paste a URL to an image from the web into a textfield and my app will load this image into the canvas.  If you want to add padding so that the image doesn't quite go all the way to the edge of its parent div, you can set the `max-width` and `max-height` properties of the canvas to something like 95%.

Answer (score 1):

To resize keeping your aspect ratio, try setting `#itemImageCanvas{ width: 100%; }` without touching it's height manually, then on your component:

1. Render the `canvas` with default size (300, 150), saved on your `state`.

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <canvas id="itemImageCanvas"
        width={this.state.canvasWidth}
        height={this.state.canvasHeight} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

2. Use se component's life cycle methods to load the image, and resize.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let image = new Image();
  image.src = 'img.jpg';
  image.onload = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      canvasWidth: image.width,
      canvasHeight: image.height
    }));
    document.getElementById('itemImageCanvas')
      .getContext('2d')
      .drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  };
}
```

Comment: The image scales quite nicely!  However, this causes the parent div that the canvas is in to be locked to the same size and aspect ratio as the canvas, which pushes all of the other components in flex boxes out of alignment.  Is there a way to have the canvas scale with the image's aspect ratio without affecting the size of the parent div the canvas is in?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, `canvas { width: 100%; }` means that the canvas takes 100% of his parent's width. If this `div` grows or shrinks, is not because of his content, it's himself or some element next to it. Now you need to set that `width` fixed/limited. Or you can also use `grid` layout to achieve that.

Comment: That makes sense.  I figured it out!  If I set max-height and max-width of the canvas to 100%, it resizes up to the size of the parent div but not larger than it.  Thanks for your help with this.